# media queries vs javascript for changing div position based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, screen

I have a large banner that contains a slider on my site, the position is `absolute`, because the banner is so wide  when I look at it on smaller screens , all you can see is the left side of it.

I was originally using `media screen only` to adjust for mobile and various screen sizes,  I would basically apply a different left negative left position for every size but this seems inefficient and also it doesnt seem to work perfeclty as I need to take into account every possible size for it to be neat.

Then I thought about javascript, but unfortunately I dont know much of it at all. Im wondering is there is a simple bit of code that I could apply to a div in js that changes its left position automatically based on screen size.

Or even any suggestions based on `media screen only` would be great thanks. My big issue with that is not knowing what left position I should apply to what resolution.

If you need more info let me know. Thank you
Adrian

Comment: "*different position for every size*" - what exactly did you try, is your positioning that complex? Relative values (in percent) should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [an article](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/10/04/10-useful-and-time-saving-javascript-snippets/) a while ago with some useful snippets, this is one of them:

> This utility is a simple approach to set width breakpoints when
>   working on responsive designs. It's a quick way to relate CSS media
>   queries in your JavaScript code as you go.

```
function isBreakPoint(bp) {
  // The breakpoints that you set in your css
  var bps = [320, 480, 768, 1024];
  var w = $(window).width(); // or window.innerWidth with plain JS
  var min, max;
  for (var i = 0, l = bps.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (bps[i] === bp) {
      min = bps[i-1] || 0;
      max = bps[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  return w > min && w <= max;
}
```

Then in your script:

```
if ( isBreakPoint(320) ) { 
  // breakpoint at 320 or less
}
if ( isBreakPoint(480) ) { 
  // breakpoint between 320 and 480
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is very useful, just wondering what is applied in the `if` statement though? Is that the essential part for getting it to relate to the `media query`, I looked at your demo and it didnt seem there was any need.Cheers

Comment: `isBreakPoint` just returns `true` or `false`, so you can use as conditional wherever and whenever you want, like on the demo. For example: `alert( isBreakPoint(320) ? 'is 320 or less' : 'is more than 320' )`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to absolutely position a banner, but assuming you need to, if the banner is an *image and resizable* you can use `method 1`.

If it *has* to be in its *original pixel-perfect size*, use `method 2` to center it in the screen.

#### method 1

```
#banner {
/* Your normal banner code */
position: absolute;
/* positioning etc. */
}

@media (max-width: {banner-size}px) {
#banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
}
```

#### method 2

```
#banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px; /* anything you want */
    left: 50%; /* you can adjust to off-center */
    margin-left: -{width/2}px;
}
```